# Using LAG for SUM in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a GPS app that saves data to the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Tracking]
(
    [id]          [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IMEI]        [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TrackTime]   [datetime] NULL,
    [Longitude]   [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Lattitude]   [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [speed]       [float] NULL,
    [CarID]       [int] NULL,
    [Country]     [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [City]        [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Area]        [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Street]      [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FullAddress] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Distance]    [float] NULL
)
```

I need to get total time of parking and total time of driving per day:

Table Sample Data

[image]

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT carid, SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,  a.trackold, a.TrackTime)) as LostTime ,TrackDay FROM (SELECT carid, TrackTime, LAG( TrackTime, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY  carid  ORDER BY carid) as trackold ,
      CONVERT(date, TrackTime) as TrackDay
  FROM T_Tracking) a  
  group by carid,TrackDay
```

Query results:

[image]

the query almost correct but i need to get the column speed (where speed <3 for stop and speed>3 for drive ), e.g. car1 parking 10 hours driving 14 hours
(parking speed < 3)

Thanks

it is gps System 
Insert a record every 1 minute per car 
the record contains the speed and the current Datetime 
the required to calculate how much the car has stoped per day and how much it was drive 
stop is not speed=0 it is speed <3 
Expected

```
select 'Car1' as CarID, '01/01/2017' as TrackDay , 240 as StopTimeInMinutes , 300 as DriveTimeInMinutes
```

Edit
sqlfiddle

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb633d
Result
[image]

New Edit

```
      SELECT 
    carid
  , TrackTime
  , LAG( TrackTime, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY  carid  ORDER BY carid) as trackold
  , CONVERT(date, TrackTime) as TrackDay
  , speed,DATEDIFF(minute, LAG( TrackTime, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY  carid  ORDER BY carid),TrackTime)
FROM T_Tracking
```

Result

[image]

the problem is when the lag record on another day there must be a condition that the record and its lag on the same day

Comment: Try before reaching the `SUM` to have a column separating the <3 from >3, probably via `CASE`, and include that column in the grouping. Also, to help us understand & test, maybe add some sample data as `INSERT` statements and the current & expected outputs for that specific sample data.

Comment: Added sqlfiddle Link

Comment: Yeah this sample doesn't seem to really relate to the fiddle or the question's images (*which, are troublesome cuz they're images*), but, try this? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb633d/6/0

Comment: thanks it is close but i need one record per day for each car with a column with how much it was stoping and anothe column with running please see my edit i need SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,  a.trackold, a.TrackTime)) where speed<3  as LostTime ,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,  a.trackold, a.TrackTime)) where speed>3  as drivetime

Answer (score 0):

First off, defining necessary-only structure, and some sample data thanks to randomization and [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) (**~50 lines**):

```
--DROP TABLE #T_Tracking
CREATE TABLE #T_Tracking
(
    [id]          [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TrackTime]   [datetime] NULL,
    [speed]       [float] NULL,
    [CarID]       [int] NULL
)
-- Those two lines made me the random data.
--INSERT INTO #T_Tracking VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, RAND() * 10, 1001)
--INSERT INTO #T_Tracking SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, TrackTime), RAND() * 10, 1001 FROM #T_Tracking WHERE CarID = 1001 ORDER BY id DESC
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #T_Tracking ON
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (1,CAST('20170716 15:55:03.350' as DATETIME),0.16923905811553, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (2,CAST('20170716 15:55:03.367' as DATETIME),2.07898632701893, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (3,CAST('20170716 15:55:03.367' as DATETIME),1.80666718899698, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (4,CAST('20170716 15:56:03.350' as DATETIME),9.94864912346075, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (5,CAST('20170716 15:56:03.367' as DATETIME),7.51657570710667, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (6,CAST('20170716 15:56:03.367' as DATETIME),6.70713362404461, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (7,CAST('20170716 15:57:03.350' as DATETIME),4.45078903833255, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (8,CAST('20170716 15:57:03.367' as DATETIME),6.47045595046756, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES (9,CAST('20170716 15:57:03.367' as DATETIME),5.24162088372108, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(10,CAST('20170716 15:58:03.350' as DATETIME),8.87269367433288, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(11,CAST('20170716 15:58:03.367' as DATETIME),7.94399400473739, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(12,CAST('20170716 15:58:03.367' as DATETIME),6.34658897830318, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(13,CAST('20170717 15:55:03.397' as DATETIME),8.29103012350227, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(14,CAST('20170717 15:55:03.397' as DATETIME),6.59994175020258, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(15,CAST('20170717 15:55:03.397' as DATETIME),5.59272074948864, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(16,CAST('20170717 15:56:03.397' as DATETIME),2.24101274328892, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(17,CAST('20170717 15:56:03.397' as DATETIME),3.25396492167535, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(18,CAST('20170717 15:56:03.397' as DATETIME),8.95021218987194, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(19,CAST('20170717 15:57:03.397' as DATETIME),0.554494328077911,1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(20,CAST('20170717 15:57:03.397' as DATETIME),3.97927461327881, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(21,CAST('20170717 15:57:03.397' as DATETIME),0.440008191277681,3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(22,CAST('20170717 15:58:03.397' as DATETIME),5.97204548751938, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(23,CAST('20170717 15:58:03.397' as DATETIME),5.60860061472591, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(24,CAST('20170717 15:58:03.397' as DATETIME),0.593327169646068,3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(25,CAST('20170718 15:55:03.427' as DATETIME),4.67974215928374, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(26,CAST('20170718 15:55:03.427' as DATETIME),3.51345008036671, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(27,CAST('20170718 15:55:03.427' as DATETIME),2.60753164190143, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(28,CAST('20170718 15:56:03.427' as DATETIME),3.20546406676272, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(29,CAST('20170718 15:56:03.427' as DATETIME),9.32640254306593, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(30,CAST('20170718 15:56:03.427' as DATETIME),4.37254464064582, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(31,CAST('20170718 15:57:03.427' as DATETIME),8.1614334079022,  1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(32,CAST('20170718 15:57:03.427' as DATETIME),7.56329435049565, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(33,CAST('20170718 15:57:03.427' as DATETIME),5.16454224115922, 3003)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(34,CAST('20170718 15:58:03.427' as DATETIME),2.81984150644997, 1001)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(35,CAST('20170718 15:58:03.427' as DATETIME),8.89421657221517, 2002)
INSERT INTO [#T_Tracking]([id],[TrackTime],[speed],[CarID]) VALUES(36,CAST('20170718 15:58:03.427' as DATETIME),8.20605160683511, 3003)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #T_Tracking OFF
```

Second, the revised query (*the answer part*). I just pretty much incorporated **dnoeth**'s remarks, some even I applied beyond his noted scope. For `ORDER` though, I used a different column than his, but they both should behave the same:

```
SELECT
    carid
  , CONVERT(date, tracktime) AS DAYDAY
  , SUM(CASE WHEN speed <  3 THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND, T.trackold, T.TrackTime) END) AS 'SPEEDING'
  , SUM(CASE WHEN speed >= 3 THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND, T.trackold, T.TrackTime) END) AS 'PARKED'
FROM (
    SELECT speed, tracktime, carid, LAG(TrackTime, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY carid, CONVERT(date, tracktime) ORDER BY id ASC) as trackold
    FROM #T_Tracking
) AS T
GROUP BY CARID, CONVERT(date, tracktime)
```

Third, the output based on **this** sample (*first time doing them, tips/improvements appreciated*):

```
carid       DAYDAY        SPEEDING    PARKED
----------- ----------    ----------- -----------
1001        2017-07-16    180         0
2002        2017-07-16    180         0
3003        2017-07-16    180         0
1001        2017-07-17    60          120
2002        2017-07-17    180         0
3003        2017-07-17    60          120
1001        2017-07-18    120         60
2002        2017-07-18    180         0
3003        2017-07-18    180         0
```

**Reminder,** please revise & safeguard against any `NULL` or `'ERROR'` issues.

Comment: thanks but not yet every car must have one record per day with sum of driving and sum of parking in your answer the car has more than one record per day

Comment: @MaherKhalil, didn't understand your comment, but I found a bunch of mistakes and fixed them, check again please.

Comment: thank but i have strange numbers in the speeding and parking the number should be less than 1440(total minutes in a day) but i get a larger numbers i have inserted an image of the result

Comment: Your images contain and use data different than fiddle, so I can't compare fiddle results to the images results. Your data image have the date columns partially hidden, and it probably have some rows hidden, and even without that typing it myself would take ages, so I can't work with them too. We should either discuss and compare on current fiddle data, or a new set of data, whichever you like. Anyways, I gotta disappear for about 2 hours.

Comment: You `order by carid`, should be `order by TrackTime` instead. And you might need to add `CONVERT(date, TrackTime)` to `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: it is normal that the fiddle data is different fiddle is too small to handle that

Comment: @MaherKhalil: Additonally you should calculate based on seconds and finaly divide by 60 to get minutes. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb633d/15

Comment: @MaherKhalil, updated with dnoeth's comments, DDL, & a data sample. Please review & post us back. If addressing current vs. expected outputs, please ensure you're addressing the data I presented, so that we could be of help. If data sample needs changes, please do tell. Oh and thanks dnoeth.